# The process has no package identity. [uwp] [Win32]

Tags: winapi, uwp

Please help me understand the concept of `metrobstyle` apps.
I have developed one `UWP` app which has `win32` exe embedded as full trust process. After I install the appx and launch then
I get parameter incorrect issue very intermittently when intermediate `win32` exe is launched .. please help me understand this.
hope someone can help

Comment: Can you please provide more detail and code? I don't understand the question yet...

Comment: It seems like you are trying to use a Windows 10 API that requires your app to run in the context of a container with a package identify. Obviousy, you need to provide more details abput your issue for anyone to be able to help you any further.